# How to upload .dmn file to jBPM business central project using KIE Rest API

Tags: drools, jbpm, kie, kie-server

I am able to upload TrafficViolation.dmn file to business central project using upload button provided in the workspace, but I want to do it programmatically using REST API provided by the kie server.

I am trying to upload TrafficViolation.dmn file to business central project  using REST API but I did find any API endpoint for the same in this [KIE Server REST API for KIE containers and business assets](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_process_automation_manager/7.11/html/deploying_and_managing_red_hat_process_automation_manager_services/kie-server-rest-api-con_kie-apis) documentation. I need an endpoint to upload DMN assets.